# Is it proper form to write $f'(x)$ in terms of $a$ when using the $x \to a$ method?

Tags: limits, derivatives

For first principles derivatives, I solve for $f'(x)$ by doing the following: $$f'(x) = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

Since $x$ approaches $a,$ the final answer will be in terms of $a.$ Is this considered proper form? I had always assumed that if you take the derivative of $f(x),$ you would get an answer in terms of $x.$ Is the $x \to a$ definition of the derivative above (the equation) incorrect? How would I rewrite it so the final answer is in terms of $x,$ if necessary?

Comment: Your very first equation is not correct. It should be either $$f'(a) = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$ or $$f'(x) = \lim_{a\to x}\frac{f(a)-f(x)}{a-x}$$ or even $$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ but *not* what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry Clement I was really tired and wrote something weird. Anyway, I changed my question to what I meant to ask. The question still stands.

Comment: Even after the edit, the comment still stands. You are writing the definition of $f'(a)$, not $f'(x)$. And indeed, in what you wrote, $x$ is a dummy variable in the RHS. The values would be the same if you replaced $x$ by $u$ everywhere in the RHS -- so the LHS cannot depend on $x$ when the RHS does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since $x$ approaches $a$, the final answer will be in terms of $a$. Is this considered proper form?

No, this is not proper. The left-hand side is looking for an answer in terms of $x$ while the right-hand side is in terms of $a$. This really doesn't make any sense. In order to fix this, you should make $a$ approach $x$, like so:

$$f'(x)=\lim_{a \to x} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$$

Now, the right-hand side will give you an answer in terms of $x$, so the above is correct.

Comment: Perfect. Exactly what I needed. You rock.